# spark ata dprocessing on multiple rows proceesing at at time

Tags: java, apache-spark

Some one could please help me on spark processing real time processing

I have a dataset and want to process it . and the scenario is while processing each row I have to check condition and based on success have to filter the data .
 I have to check any two rows in the data set and want to apply some conditions if condition is true in both the rows then I have to take the two rows , If any row fails then I should not take either of them .

here is the challenge , From Spark RDD each time I will get one row only  So how to condition both the rows together in one attempt

Comment: It would be nice if you could specify input and output dataset as an example

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a mapPartitions. That should give you access to all the records in a partition.

Here's some sample code (JAVA)

```
    JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    JavaRDD<String> inputRdd = ctx.parallelize(Stream.of("record1", "record2", "record3")
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))
    );

    JavaRDD<String> resultsRdd = inputRdd.mapPartitions(recItr -> {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

        recItr.forEachRemaining(rec -> {
            //insert checking conditions here
            results.add(rec); //add to result list
        });

        return results.iterator(); //return list
    });

    resultsRdd.foreach(rec -> System.out.println(rec));
```